# Why aren't my admob ads aren't showing up on the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

Here is what I have. I am not sure what to do from here as everything is connected. It has displayed once before than has never came back after that.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myBanner: GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

    myBanner.adUnitID = "(my ad ID)"

    myBanner.rootViewController = self
    myBanner.delegate = self
    myBanner.load(request)
}
```

Comment: you set the delegate already so what is the error that you get? check this method `func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError)`

Comment: i don't know if this means anything but it says:                                                                    Tap[19435:16042629] Failed to create remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}